# UK visa refusal for my wife to accompany me on my business trip

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I am travelling to the UK in the 3rd week of November on a business visit and intend to stay for more 10 days, along with my wife, when my business is over. I have my visa, but my wife's visa was refused.

I transferred around 1100 pounds into her accounts close to her visa appointment date, with an intent to enhance her financial strength. She has been working for the last 2 years and we submitted her salary slips, bank statements (last 6 months) and her latest ITR. Because of this fund transfer, we mentioned that she would be bearing 75% of the trip cost and the rest 25% would be borne by me. However, I didn't provide any cover letter or any of my salary slips or bank statements along with her application.

The rejection letter states two reasons primarily:

> 1. The most recent credit amount of GBP £1100 doesn't match with the salary credits reflected in the statement. Also, the documents and information that you have provided do not demonstrate the origin of the funds held in this account: therefore, bank statement does not satisfactorily demonstrate your income or whether these funds are under your personal control. Therefore, I am not satisfied that this bank statement is an accurate reflection of your personal and financial circumstances.
> 2. Moreover you state that you are married and that your husband intends to travel to the UK and will contribute towards the cost of your trip. However, the documents you have presented do not demonstrate any details about your husband, his whereabouts income or employment. I am therefore not satisfied you have accurately demonstrated your husband is able to meet the cost of your trip as claimed. This undermines your credibility and therefore I am not satisfied your intentions to visit the UK are as stated.
>
> Given the above I am not satisfied that you are a genuine visitor and that you will leave the UK at the end of your visit. I am not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry for a purpose that is permitted by the visitor routes. I am not satisfied that you have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to your visit without working or accessing public funds. This includes the cost of the return or onward journey and cost of planned activities. Therefore your application is refused under paragraphs V4.2(a)(c)(e).

I wish to reapply, providing the following documents: cover letter signed by me confirming that I would bear all her expenses, my salary slips, bank statements, company's invitation letter, hotel details (with both of our names). Along with that, the funds I deposited in her account had been withdrawn by me and now I am thinking of mentioning that my intent was to share the money with her as a gift to let her bear the expense, and there was a mutual consent. Now, that money is under my control and I will take full responsibility of bearing the expenses.

Let me know if there is something else which I need to do or follow a different approach. The application was refused today and I wish to reapply early next week.

Comment: Although the documents you plan to provide will normally address all the questions, the key statement to me is _I am not satisfied that you are **genuinely** seeking entry for a purpose that is permitted by the visitor routes_. I am inclined to suspect that a second refusal is more likely than not. When they hit you with a+c+e that’s essentially throwing the book at you, everything including the kitchen sink. Basically they do not intend to approve the visa regardless. My advice would be not to reapply for this trip.

Comment: @Priyanshu Kumar Did you link your application to your wife’s via the GWF number? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56419/allocation-of-shares-of-expenditure-to-dependants-on-standard-visitor-visa-appli

Comment: No, I didn't. Can we do that? What is the procedure to do that?Also, we are travelling on different dates- she would join me when my business trip ends, which is 1st Dec, thats when she is going to travel to London. We both have our return flight from London, thought different flights

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen I'm not sure I agree in this case. The "not genuine" part sounds like it's mostly because there was a mystery transfer of £1100 into the wife's account and because the application said "My husband will support me" but provided no evidence that the husband could do that. All of that seems easily overcome (except insofar as the husband providing £1100 may still be seen as "funds not under your personal control".)

Comment: @Priyanshu Kumar Since your wife would be entering separately, I would include your GWF number in the ‘Additional information’ section at the end of her application.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I respectfully disagree and I believe Gayot Fow’s a+c+e canonical supports my position. A+C+E are not **easily overcome**. Hopefully he returns with the results of the reapplication.

Comment: "I transferred around 1100 pounds in her accounts close to her visa appointment date, with an intent to enhance her financial strength.". This is often (always?) wrong and it has weaken the application. See money parking.

Comment: Since my visa application is approved, so shall i attach a copy of my visa along with her re-application or still mention my GWF number in this case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a similar problem earlier this year. You first need to make sure that you link your applications via the GWF number. In her application she can submit your bank statement, your job details (including a proof of employment, invitation letter, your pay-slips) and a proof of address that you both live together. It is important to show a link that will force you and your wife to go back to your country. For example in our case the daughter (12 yo) didn't travel with us and she stayed home with my parents, we got a letter from her school to show that she's enrolled there and that we can't leave her behind so we are definitely going back. I provided a cover letter where I mentioned that the first application was rejected and that we are applying again to answer any doubts and to prove that we are genuine. If you own properties in your country you can also use that as a proof that you'll go back. They are always suspicious that you'll overstay so you need to make sure you answer that for them. Transferring money to your wife's account is a bit suspicious. You need to mention that you will cover her expenses in the cover letter (I wrote the cover letter in my own name not her's). You also need to prove that you'll be staying at the same hotel/apartment together and provide details of your trip including flights and airlines (if booked). Also mention what she'll be doing while you are attending your business meetings for example. Just to let you know my wife was going to attend her graduation and the rejection she got was that "they are not convinced she is going to attend the graduation" also said "they are not convinced about her degree from the University", it sounds non-since but they work on ticking boxes and if you fail to provide the evidence they need they'll reject your application. our mistake was that we didn't give them enough information that she's only there to attend the graduation.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes, I agree now that transferring money without showing some basis ay sound suspicious, therefore, I have transferred the money back to my account and now I will mention in the cover letter that I would be covering her entire expense now-tickets(though our flights are different- I got to return on the business flight provided by the company, she would be travelling by a fdiffent flight, stay(which would be together). Also, she would join me once my business trip is over. We both have got NOC from our respective firms- so not sure why they are asking intent.