# Travelling to UK for tourism purpose with family

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I've planned to travel to UK with my family that's my father and mother. My mother are self sufficient to show their basic income for the trip. I'm employed but joined the present employment 4months back, so I don't have sufficient amount to show. My father is having sufficient balance to show that he will be sponsoring me for the purpose of tourism. We have already booked the package from our tour agent. So the question is:
1. Can the officer reject my application considering my application individually?
2. Can the officer reject my application considering the situation that I'm traveling with my parents for tourism purpose?

Please help me with this.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

The answer to both of your questions is ‘Yes’ if the ECO doesn’t consider that you personally meet the eligibility requirements and qualify for a visa in your own right. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF You should not make travel arrangements until you’ve received your visa - UKVI does not require you to provide flight and hotel bookings with your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But even if I'm showing that I'm dependant on my father for the purpose of tourism.

Comment: If you are a fully grown adult with a job you are not dependant on your parents. Your parents can gift you a holiday if they like but the UK doesn't have to give you a visa for it.

Comment: Thanks. But we all my mother father and myself we are traveling together. And we all collectively do have our cost of the trip in my father's account. And, he will be there with me with a covering letter mentioning the same specifically.

Comment: @Akshay sawant No-one can answer your questions with complete certainty. Needing a sponsor is sometimes a negative factor; your father’s application may be refused; the ECO is not obliged to grant entire families a visa even if they are travelling together etc., etc. There is an excellent schematic here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy of the risk assessment process (it is for a Schengen visa however the risk factors considered are likely to be very similar).

Comment: Thanks. But we all are making different applications. I'm also producing my pay slips and bank statements and explaining that why I don't have the sufficient balance. And also explaining that how my father is having sufficient funds to sponsor my trip. We are not applying a collective visa. But my concern is that it's pretty logical if you have cost trip in your fathers account or you have it  individually you all gonna travel together right? Does that gonna make any difference??

Comment: @Akshay sawant You have to state if you’re travelling with any one and you’ll need to link the applications via the GWF number if your father is the primary applicant https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56419/allocation-of-shares-of-expenditure-to-dependants-on-standard-visitor-visa-appli Your question relates to whether you personally can be refused, the answer is yes, you can be but you may not be. There are lots of questions on TSE where applicants had strong sponsors but were still refused.