# How to apply for UK travel visa with my parents

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications

Planning to apply for UK tourist visa for me and my parents , i have got enough documents but not my parents except passport and identity card.

Is there any chance of visa refusal considering there is not enough documents for my parents, and do i need to apply visa separately or together?

Would be great if someone could answer my queries.

Comment: Assuming your parents are not dependent on you, if they can’t demonstrate that they meet the eligibility requirements then there is a very high chance of refusal. Reading this Visit guidance may help https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF  Each person has to complete an application https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56419/allocation-of-shares-of-expenditure-to-dependants-on-standard-visitor-visa-appli

Comment: Each person must apply individually for a visa to enter the UK. In the process, you are asked with whom you are travelling, if anyone, but there is no group application procedure. Yes, they risk refusal if they offer absolutely no supporting documents; applying with only a passport is almost inviting a refusal (and, depending on your premise for entering the UK, may jeopardise your own visa application).