# UK visitor Visa for child with mother

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, children, pakistani-citizens

I am applying for a UK visitors visa from Pakistan with my 8 year old son. I completed the online form and it is directing me towards payment. Do I need to complete my form, pay for my visa and then apply for my child and then pay for him?

I am afraid we might get different appointments for biometric verification. Also, the number of family members has not been asked. I was only asked to enter the number of financially dependent kids, but the kids are dependent on their father, not me. I want to mention that I intend to travel with one child only while others will stay back home.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56419/allocation-of-shares-of-expenditure-to-dependants-on-standard-visitor-visa-appli

Answer (score 1):

Asma, I have gone through from a similar process two weeks ago where I applied my wife and kids Visa from Pakistan.

- Yes, can complete an application first and then proceed with the other one.
- In the Kids application, the system will ask about the parent details and those who are travelling with the kids so this will cover your association with the Application
- Write a covering letter to mention about the kids you will be leaving behind and make sure to explain who will take care of them in your absence.
- You may get the appointment with 10 to 20 mins of difference but this does not matter just reach the centre on your first appointment time and let them know that you have your kid with yourself
- Currently, the just scan the documents so the staff member at the counter will scan the documents one by one but your application will be forwarded as a group in the same bag however your both applications will have the different GWF

I hope this clarifies your query!

Best of luck with your visa application

Comment: The parent's GWF number can be (should be) mentioned directly in the child's application, in the "Additional information" field.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! I also need to know which documents do I need to submit? They are just asking for my passport

Comment: You need to submit all supporting documents including financial records, text returns, hotel booking (if any), sponsor evidence and sponsor documents. Family registration certificate and kids birth certificate. Any previous visa and stamps copies. in short everything which can support your claim that you will return to your home country after visiting UK
https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide

Comment: And one thing you need to make sure, please do arrange your documents properly using the separators (you can download that once your application gets completed). Separators are printed cover papers which categorize your provided documents. 
another way is that you can purpose the service from the centre in around 1710 PKR they will arrange your documents or you can also avail the premium lounge in around 7000 PKR where you will get assisted services.

Comment: Also plz let me know how to cancel this application and start a new one as I want to make changes. thank you

Comment: You can always make edits to your existing application

Comment: Its only allowing edits to certain answers such as kids info, travel info but not others.

Comment: Can I leave this application and start a new one all over?

Comment: You can start over if you are not able to edit the existing application

Comment: Hi, Do I need to make a different file for the child and myself or I can organize all supporting documents in one file and separate them using separators?

Comment: The way I organized the file was
All supporting documents with bank statements were with the primary applicant whereas the children birth certificates were the only document I put with their application.
When they scanned the document they make it one collective submission even our passports were put in one bag.