# Applying for UK Visit Visa

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, vfs-global

I've been having a lot of trouble with applying for a uk visit visa. Background is that I'm an Indian expat, living in Qatar. Single. My parents and my sister also live in Qatar. My Dad and I have jobs (in separate organizations). For this trip, I wanted to take all of them; and we were planning to spend about a week in London.

1. While filling out applications, it is required for each of us to fill out forms separately. For the part talking about expenses, I put in 8000 GBP in mine, and 2000 GBP in the others. Furthermore,  I had it mentioned in the remarks section of each applicant that I was the primary and mentioned the GWF numbers of the travelling parties. Is this right? I'm really confused about the dependents, as my parents are not dependent on me, but my sister is dependent on my dad as she just graduated. But for the purpose of the trip, I'm the primary. My dad offered to help with some of the expenses, but I will be paying for most of it. Not sure what 'dependent' means in this situation.
2. My sister had filled out the forms of my mom, dad and herself. In doing so, she used her email for all of them. Due to recent change, once application is done, and payment made, it automatically takes you to vfs website using info you provided on the application. The problem is that now when we go to the vfs login page from the application website (gov.uk) it shows my sisters email address and only one application. What can be done here?
3. I live in Qatar, and I have a bank account here as well as back in India. The Indian account has much more in deposits than the Qatar account. If we find a way to untangle the mess above, should i provide both bank statements?
4. It is mentioned that only the primary has to provide evidence of supporting documents. However, in the vfs site, you have to upload something to move forward. And furstratingly enough, there is no option to do the passport and residence permit of Qatar, which is mandatory. What evidence am i supposed to provide for my mom and sister, both of whom are not employed, nor have any supporting documents as such?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56419/allocation-of-shares-of-expenditure-to-dependants-on-standard-visitor-visa-appli

Comment: You want to spend £14,000 on a week's holiday for four people in London? Unless you're extremely rich, that's a massive over-estimate of what it will cost. You're talking about six months' wages for the average worker in the UK.

Comment: I think there has been a misunderstanding. the 8000 in mine was supposed to be the total for all parties. 2000 GBP each. I assumed the linking of applications through mentioning the GWF numbers in remarks section would clarify that.

Comment: @frodocorleone Honestly, even £8000 seems a lot to me. But your application says you'll be spending £8000 and your other family members will be spending £2000 each so, no, that's not right.

Comment: How should I answer the expenses question for each of the family member ?

Comment: @frodocorleone Read the question I linked to in my comment. And yes, you should supply both sets of bank statements if you can substantiate the transactions and the balances show you can afford the trip. If just one account shows that, and there are no inter-account transfers for UKVI to pick up on, personally I’d just include that one https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: Hi, I did read that question you linked to before posting. The problem is that 1. It doesnt say what I'm supposed to do with the columns for the others who are travelling with me (inputting 0 doesnt work, and there is no option to write things like N/A) 2. The other members are not my dependents outside of this trip. In the answer you linked, there is a major assumption of a primary and dependents - I'm not sure which context.