# Applying with minors for UK Standard visit visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, minors

I am applying for the UK standard visit visa.
I have filled my application and also entered details of my children traveling with me (it suggested that they still need to have separate applications filled)

Now I have started filling my **11 years** old daughter's application, and
there are few things the form is asking which are a bit confusing:

> What is the ownership status of your home

Shall I choose 'other' and highlight that she is not renting it?

> How much money are you personally planning to spend on your visit to the UK? (Required)

Should I put the same amount for my daughter as well which I entered for myself?

> What is the total amount of money you spend each month? (Required)

Not sure what to fill here, it does not allow me to enter 0, is it OK to enter pocket money amount?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas) This might also help https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56419/allocation-of-shares-of-expenditure-to-dependants-on-standard-visitor-visa-appli

Comment: You are filling up the old form. Fill up the new form on gov.uk, that one is much easier.