# Dependent wife with no marriage certificate: UK visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I'm applying for a visit visa to the UK for my wife and me, my wife is dependent on me so we will apply for 1 set of salary documents that is mine as I pay for everything in our household.

The problem is we don't have a marriage certificate since our marriage was solemnised 30 years ago in a religious ceremony in a small village and never had officially registered it since there was no legal rule to get a certificate back then in India.

My wife and I have each other's names on our Indian passports in the spouse's name. I talked to a lawyer and he said he can get an affidavit done for us but will this work? also, do I need to provide a letter in my wife's application saying I'm her husband and I will take care of all expenses and she can take money from my account?

Comment: Since England is where "common-law marriage" originated, and the UK has also more recently had a fairly broad acceptance of life partnership by whatever name, I am fairly confident that it should be possible to establish that you are married without a certificate (provided that the marriage is valid under Indian law, which it seems to be, and that neither of you is married to anyone else).  However, I don't know what documents you would need, and I have no experience with visa applications under similar circumstances, so I will leave it to someone else to answer.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56419/allocation-of-shares-of-expenditure-to-dependants-on-standard-visitor-visa-appli