# UK Tourist Visa from India - Self-employed and savings

Tags: uk, paperwork, tourist-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

My spouse and I are applying for a UK tourist visa from India. We intend to visit London during December for 10 days.

We have a company and we both are partners in the company, from which we get consultancy fees and reimbursement for expenses we undertake on the company's behalf.

As a couple, we have a joint account where we have savings of over 10,000 GBP, which have been built consistently over 3 years. We want to show these funds as savings in both our visa applications. I would like to know, should I mention 5,000 GBP for mine and 5,000 for his and attach bank statements? Will that create suspicion since the statement will show a 10,000 GBP balance, but we declare 5000 GBP?

Also, my husband has some additional savings he holds jointly with his mother. Those savings are for his mother's retirement and have largely come in from insurance payouts and sale of real estate following his father's demise in 2020. Now this savings account has another 12,000 GBP, which can be accessed by my husband (the actual balance in this account is over 60,0000 GBP, of which 12,0000 GBP is my husband's). Should we show this 12,000 GBP then in my husband's visa form? If yes, should we write 66,6000 GBP OR 12,000 GBP as our savings?

Furthermore, we have all receipts for the insurance payouts, real estate, which we are open to attaching. Additionally, we are mentioning that the funds in the account are largely for his mother's retirement and her plan to purchase real estate in the next 2 months - since she retires in early 2024.

To show our ties back home, we have several investments, real estate property in India.

Requesting to help, in showing what saving fund amount to show and mention from the above.

Comment: For clarity, what is the total cost of the trip? Is the account with the additional savings held with your husband’s mother in *both* their names? Is there any official paperwork proving £120k of the £600k balance belong to your husband?

Comment: We are estimating 2000 GBP as the trip expense per person. Yes the account is held in both their names

Comment: In regards to the 12000GBP there's no specific paperwork since these are again savings made by him from his account in which he receives his fees to this account which he holds with his mother.

Comment: There's a discrepancy in the amounts because sometimes you use 12000 (12k) and sometimes 120000 (120k), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you follow the advice in [Allocation of shares of expenditure to dependants on Standard Visitor visa applications](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56419/allocation-of-shares-of-expenditure-to-dependants-on-standard-visitor-visa-appli) regarding allocation of funds (relates to dependents, but the principle is the same).

The joint account with mother is somewhat more complicated IMHO. I see two options to deal with it:

- Include the £12,000 as part of your husband’s savings, and provide statements for the account, supporting paperwork showing the source of the funds (including all transfers from your husband’s account), and a letter from the mother confirming that £12,000 of the account balance is available for her son’s use.
- Alternatively, your husband could consider transferring the £12,000 belonging to him into his own account and providing all the supporting paperwork.

You can explain in a covering letter.

Comment: Understood. Option 1 seems more suitable for us, just that instead of combining with mine - can we keep show his account with his mother along with a declaration from the mother? If yes,what should be written in the visa application as savings for him - 66000 GBP or 12000 GBP

Comment: @Aviary I’m not sure I understand your point. If you have a joint savings account with your husband your savings are *already* combined with his, plus both your incomes come from the same source (your company) *and* you’re travelling together. Write the savings amount justified by the supporting paperwork - you can’t write £66k if the money isn’t your husband’s. Make sure all the information reconciles, and keep it simple and easy to understand - ECOs are unlikely to have much inclination or time to wade through masses of paper and complicated financial scenarios.

Comment: Understood. We can have the 12000 GBP transferred to the joint account we hold. My only hitch on doing the transfer was it shouldn't look like a situation wherein the money was transferred for visa purpose inspite of providing a cover letter, declaration and all bank records

Comment: @Aviary It’s a judgement call. If you can unequivocally prove that the £12k *belongs to your husband* (ie show an unbroken trail from him, because the money was transferred from his own account, and originated from his income from the company) then I personally don’t see a problem. The issue of funds parking for visa purposes arises if the money isn’t actually his, or he can’t provide definitive proof that it is his.You can’t have your cake & eat it.Either you apply based only on the £10k savings, or you include the extra £12k and document it. Or transfer the funds now, wait 6 months to apply.