# UK visa fees when traveling with a minor?

Tags: visas, uk, children, standard-visitor-visas, fees-and-charges

I am filling out an application for a UK visitors visa and I am planning on traveling with my child who is a minor. What visa fees am I required to pay?

Comment: I am not sure whether it makes a difference, but can you please add your and the minors nationality and your relationship with the minor.

Comment: @Willeke the phrase "my child" generally means that there is a parent/child relationship.

Comment: @phoog Generally, yes, but specially with ESL and possible step parents you can not be sure. And it is an easy thing to add when adding nationalities.

Answer (score 5):

> I am filling out an application for a UK visitors visa and I am planning on traveling with my child who is a minor. What visa fees am I required to pay?

If you are planning to travel with a child under 18, you must...

1. Apply for a Standard Visitor Visa for yourself;
2. Apply for a Standard Visitor Visa (child visitor) for your child;
3. Pay for your application; and
4. Pay for your child's application;
5. Make a biometrics appointment for yourself; and
6. Make a biometrics appointment for your child.

What this amounts to, is you and your child must make two full applications and pay the fee for both applications.  UKVI has stated that the amount of work necessary to process an application is not dependent upon the applicant's age, so the fee is the same for all applicants.

Notes...

- They stopped issuing parent/child visas as a single visa about 17
  years ago.
- Fees for the Standard Visitor Visa will increase (allegedly) in April 2016 and (allegedly) October 2016. They are getting the details approved right now.
- Related article here:
  [How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas/51592#51592)

Comment: It's a bit late now to get the details approved for a fee increase in April 2016, isn't it? If it goes through, would they demand back payment from all who have filed in the last 6 weeks?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, email from the Home Office dated 26 Feb that starts... **"Further to my letter in January, I am writing to inform you that the legislation (laid on 11 January), which sets maximum amounts that the Home Office can charge for broad categories of visa, immigration and nationality applications, is now in force.   The Home Office laid further legislation in Parliament on 26 February, which will make changes to specific visa, immigration and nationality application fees."** I have not followed the details, hence my use of 'allegedly'.  They will not demand retrospective payment tho