# UK visitors visa for my son, 2 years and I

Tags: visas, uk

We are residing in New Zealand. Going to London to visit my mother and stepdad.  I would like to know by the income and expenditures it asks for the GBP in pounds.

1. Do I calculate my NZ dollars into pounds before entering?
2. Also, Do I have to fill in another visa application for my son, 2 years old?
3. Also, we might be flying via LA. Do I need a transit visa for America?

Answer (score 4):

> Do I calculate my NZ dollars into pounds before entering?

They don't care as long as you state on the form which currency you are using, looking at the form's instructions...

[image]

If you do decide to convert the amounts to Sterling, they like it if you use [Oanda](https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/) spot rate because it's the one they are accustomed to. But you should always explain which rate and market source you are using in the remarks section.

> Do I have to fill in another visa application for my son, 2 years old?

Yes, even if the child is 1 day old, you need to submit an application for them. If you are applying as a family, you do not have to duplicate all the evidence for the child. Your own evidence is sufficient.

> Also we might be flying via LA. Do i need a transit visa for America

This depends upon your nationality. On this site we use  [Do I need a US visa to transit (or layover) through an American airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-transit-through-an-american-airport) as a canonical way to answer questions about transit visas for the US.

There's some general information about how to make the process smoother using the parent's GWF number here: [How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas/51592#51592)