# Do we need to create separate accounts for our children to apply for a UK visit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, family, applications

My wife, three kids and I want to apply for UK visitor visas.

Do we need to create five different accounts for the online applications or can we all apply from the same account?

Comment: Hi malik, welcome to Travel.SE. I've proposed an edit to your post to clear up some up the grammar to make it a bit easier for people to read, I also added some UK & visa tags and removed the 'germany' tag as it wasn't clear how this was related to the question (given German citizens would not need a visa for the UK). Feel free to edit your post to add tags specifying where you are a citizen or resident of if you like.

Comment: @TimMalone sorry, it seems that my edit overruled yours, feel free to edit my edit :) I am sure your English is better than mine.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Haha yeah that happens sometimes. Thanks for commenting! You did a great job and pretty much the same things I edited, I just submitted another proposed edit to fix some spelling in the title as well.

Comment: it's utterly impossible to answer Visa questions, where the questioner does **not state what country they are from**

Comment: The ages of the children are also relevant!

Comment: I am half-minded to HAMMER this question as a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas but the issue about separate accounts muddies the waters. Community can decide.

Answer (score 3):

> Do we need to create five different accounts?

Yes, each applicant uses a separate account. Parents make them for their children, but only one set of evidence is required for the whole family.

Each and every person in the family pays the full fee. The fee must be paid from the applicant's own account at visa4UK. There is no facility to gang pay for a group unless you are a licensed tour operator.

You didn't ask, but this is a tip: Finish the primary's application first (assume the father) and write down the GWF number.

Then the secondary parent completes the application and puts the primary's GWF number in the remarks section.

Then the applications are completed for each child putting the parents' GWF numbers on their applications.

When all the applications are ready, submit them all in one go. This will maximize the chances of having the same biometrics appointment.  If they schedule different biometric appointments for the children, you can come back here and ask a new question about what to do.

---

Per comments...

- age of the children is irrelevant. Even a newborn babe in arms has
  to apply with their own passport and pay the full fee. The only dividing attribute is whether they are over 18 or not, and in that case they are 'adults' and 'children' does not apply to applicants over 18.
- nationality of the applicant is irrelevant when using the online
  system. Yes, there are special carve-outs for Syrian nationals and
  the like, but these are thought to be transitory and it's only 1 pop-up anyway. Americans who use
  the online system see exactly the same screens as Indian nationals. 
  Nationality comes in to play at the risk assessment stage (after submission). Some
  nationalities do not use the online system because they do not
  require an entry clearance; they simply show up and use their passport, but that's a different story. Some nationalities have fee exemptions owing to treaties, but that's also a different story. Also, more and more Americans/Canadians are applying for entry clearance even though they do not need to (the laser embossing on an entry clearance is more impressive and shinier than the 'leave to enter' stamp used at the airport).
- See also:
  [How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas/51592#51592)

Comment: Given that the application website allows users to complete applications for others, why is it necessary to create separate accounts for each applicant?

Comment: @phoog, the outcome can (and often is) different for each family member. A family of 4 might have 1 refused, or 2 refused, or whatever. There's also some accounting considerations.