# How do I create a family application for standard visitor visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, family, applications

I am planning to travel to UK for tourism with two other family members. Do I need to submit separate applications or a single application with details of all the family members?

Comment: Also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas