# UK visa for a family of 4

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, family, applications

We (myself, wife and two children) are planning to visit UK in the summer (I have already started to regret it!!).

I have some visa related questions:

1. Does each applicant have to create their own login/password and create an application?
2. Do minors need their own login/password and application ? do they need their own email address?
3. Do I have to make four separate payments, one for each of us?
4. If I submit four separate applications, what is the guarantee that I will get a same-day appointment for all of us. Obviously, I hate to make four separate trips to the interview center which means my wife and I have to take time off from work four times.
5. Is the visa fee for children the same as for adults?

Comment: There's information on how to apply for multiple people including children in [this Q&A](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas). Perhaps review it, and then edit your question to focus on what is still unclear. Normally, there should be 1 question only.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for responding. I already read the earlier link that you mentioned but i still wasn't clear. I am not sure where Part 7 and 9 are in the visa apply process. The sections are not numbered. I am trying to apply for visa through www.gov.uk website which is a sorry excuse for a website.

Comment: Hi, I saw these 2 points in the previous link are these:

1. Children need their own login and password.
2. A single email address can be used for the entire family.

The 2 points seem to contradict each other. If point #1 is true, then how can point #2 be true too ? I tried to use my own email address for one of my sons and every time I login, it keeps taking me to **my** application as the primary and I am not able to create my son's application. So, it's clear that my 2 sons need their own email addresses and logins.

Comment: Did you use your email for the login name? Don't, basically. The login names must be different, but the email you use within the login can be the same. (I'm assuming).

Comment: Hi Mkenndy,

On the gov.uk website, there is no such thing as "login name". To create a new application, they only ask for an "email address" and a password. if you use an existing email address, it just takes you to the existing application instead of creating a new application. It sucks! obviously gov.uk is a newly designed system and they are still evolving it.

Comment: Thanks to google "+" addressing, I was able to use my gmail address for my 2 sons without creating new ones. I can use my gmail id with a "+"

my email address:  xyz@gmail.com
email for son #1:    xyz+son1@gmail.com
email for son #2:    xyz+son2@gmail.com

the great thing about this is all emails to my son's email address will still be directed to my email address xyz@gmail.com but as far as gov,uk is concerned, the email addresses for my sons are unique.

https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html

Google is just amazing!

Comment: That's great news! And very interesting to me (because I have children too).