# Can I apply and pay as a group for UK visit visas?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I cannot pay for courier charges for UK visit visa for my family. I'm using a UPS label. I tried to pay as a group but I cannot. Do I have to apply individually?

Comment: I did a bit of an edit to make it clearer what you're asking. If I've misunderstood, apologies, and you can make your own edits.

Comment: Very similar to [How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51582/13639), the main answer there says *"Payments should be separate."*

Comment: Please see the linked article about making a family application.  The information is current and has helped a lot of people, if it does not fully satisfy your need, then please ask a new, and very detailed question, thanks.