# application as family for uk visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, family

I and my family had 10 years UK multiple entry visitor visa which expired about 2 years back.  I want to apply for the same again.    have filled up my application online and saved it.  I want to add my wife and son's application, but I am directed to visa fees payment.  How do I do it?  Do I pay for myself first and then ii would be given a choice of adding each family member?  can I fill all 3 applications under 1 account?

Comment: Also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas

Answer (score 1):

You will have to fill up each application separately and pay for each application separately, you can use the same card though. After the payment when you get to the VFS Appointment select the same date for everyone with consecutive appointment times. Then go to the VFS together and let them know you're applying as a family.

It is also helpful if you mention your GWF Number in the applications of your family members.