# Unemployed wife for the uk visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I Will be travelling soon To the uk with my hubby and baby girl but i dont have a  job or any bank account. My husband Will provide for our vacation. Can this be an issue ?

Comment: It’s not an issue in itself. Single parent earning is a pretty common thing.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's entirely normal for only one parent to work. As long as your husband earns enough that you can reasonably afford a trip to the UK, there should be no issue with that.

The related question [How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51582/11491) explains how to link your visa applications together. (Ignore the fact that it says "with young children" – the "family" part is all that matters.)