# How do I apply for a visa for my 2 year old son?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, children

Have already submitted my visa application, only then I was told my 2 years son need his separate own application. How do I submit it and do I have to send evidence documents twice?
And also do I pay a separate visa fees and another appointment?

Comment: To which country are you applying? Typically you submit his application in exactly the same way as your own, quoting your reference in his application. You submit your documents together, and you both have to pay the fee and give biometrics.

Comment: OP has already applied, so his documents are likely already submitted. @Traveller can you post an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you submit your child’s application in exactly the same way as your own, quoting your reference in the child’s application. The same fee is payable for both applications. If you don’t submit the applications at the same time you will need to provide documentation with the subsequent application.

If you are applying to the UK, see [How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas). If you’ve not attended your biometric appointment yet you might be able to synchronise the dates once you’ve submitted your son’s application.