# Family visa application to the UK

Tags: visas, uk, applications, family

I plan to make my application for UK work visa at the same time with my wife and children. But we reside in different countries, which means that locations in which to make appointments will be different.My question is: is it possible to make an online application at the same time as a family, and then my wife and children schedule an appointment to give biometrics later where they now reside?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a ‘family’ application, each person travelling needs to apply separately. Since your family’s visas are dependent on you getting yours, I suggest you wait until you’ve received your decision before submitting the remaining applications, cross-referencing them to your application GWF number. This [How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas) may help you do that.