# Applying UK Visitor Visa for my Parents

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I am applying for a UK visitor visa for my Parents. Me and my wife will be sponsoring their whole trip as we both are working here in the UK.

Questions in regards to filling in the forms:

1. My father used to do business and is now retired. He has around 2500 GBP as savings and 2 properties which are worth a lot. Will that be enough sufficient funds to mention on the application form?
   My mother is unemployed and housewife. She is a dependent on my father.
2. I will be providing a invitation/sponsorship letter mentioning my and my wife's salary and stating that we are fully sponsoring their trip.
   I am also attaching a cover letter with the Application form. Regarding the cover letter, do we need to provide 2 separate cover letters for both applications or just one will be sufficient from my Father? These are 2 separate applications but I want them to go as one. Is it possible?
3. There is a question in the form - "How much money are you planning to spend on your visit to the UK?". What should I write in here because I will be sponsoring them for everything?

Answer (score 1):

1. UK Immigration Rules don’t  specify a minimum savings/income requirement. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules What matters is that an applicant has sufficient funds available to them to cover the costs trip, and that those costs are proportionate to their overall financial situation.
2. One cover letter should be sufficient. Your mother’s application is dependent on your father’s, see [How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas) for advice on how to link the two applications
3. Enter the planned cost. If you’re paying for everything the amount you enter here should match the amount in the later question about how much the sponsor is paying.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. There is nothing primary and secondary in UK application form. There are 2 separate applications with two separate GWF numbers. I don't know where to link the Primary to secondary.
If you can elaborate on that, that would be very helpful/

Comment: The thing is how do i make sure I get the visa appointment with embassy at the same date and time for both of them?
Is there a way to get this?

Comment: @Shashank Agrawal As explained in the question I linked to, you would first complete the application for the primary (in this case, your father) and indicate in Part 9 that they are the primary. Write down their GWF number. Then proceed to make a fresh application for your mother. Put the primary's GWF number in Part 9 of her application. You should be able to choose the same date for the visa appointments via the online system once you’ve completed both applications.

Comment: Hi, There is no Part 9 in the form. No numbering. There are just different sections. There is one question - 
Dependent Details -  Does anyone rely on you for financial support?
Include both those travelling with you and those who are not.
Here I have included my mother's name. But on my mother's application form there is nothing like this.
I want to make sure the visa office sees these two application together so they know that my Mother does not have any income or savings and she is dependent on my Father.
How do i do that?

Comment: @Shashank AFAIK, the only way you can be sure that they link the two applications is to quote your father’s application reference number in her application (if there’s no Part 9 per the linked question, put it in the space for additional information at the end of her application). In your father’s application you’ll state that he’s travelling with her.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will do that. One more thing, my mother is unemployed and does not have much in savings. So do i need to create an affidavit from my father declaring that she is his responsibility and he takes care of everything from household and other stuff?

Comment: @Shashank Agrawal IMHO an affidavit is not necessary. Your father will state your mother is his dependent in his application. An affidavit isn’t worth the paper it’s written on - it doesn’t add anything to the declaration that everything in the application is true, which is what your father certified when he submits it. If you have any more questions, please post them separately.