# How do I indicate "visiting a family friend" in the UK Standard Visitor Visa application?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, minors

When applying as a minor for the UK Standard Visitor Visa, there is a question about "Private addresses in the UK" and the relationship with the person living at the private address.

We are traveling as a family to visit a family friend. The question about the relationship with the person at the address has no choice for "Family friend." What could be done in this case?

The exact question is as follows:

> You have said that you will be staying at these addresses in the UK. Are any of these a person's home address?

If you select Yes we are presented with these choices

> Telephone number of Mr. XYZ
>
> Their relationship to you

The choices are: Adopted child, Brother, Brother-in-law, Child, Child's spouse (daughter-in-law or son-in-law), Daughter, Daughter-in-law, Father, Father-in-law, Grandchild, Grandparent, Husband, Mother, Mother-in-law, Parent, Sister, Sister-in-law, Son, Son-in-law, Spouse (husband or wife), Step-child, Step-parents, Step-sister or brother, Unmarried partner, Wife

> Country of Nationality
>
> What permission do they have to be in the UK?

Comment: What is the actual text of the question? What relationship choices are offered by the form?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with the details

Comment: Is there a preceding question that might lead to the automated choices you mention? For example, a question as to whether you have family in the UK? Has the main applicant completed their application yet?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas

Comment: The previous question just asks the address(es) where one intends to stay in the UK. I am the main applicant and I completed the application. Still have to attend the biometric appointment. Would it make sense to answer no to the above question and mention this in the remarks section?

Comment: @Tej What did you answer to ‘purpose of visit’?

Comment: Tourism (including visiting family and friends)

Comment: @Tej Where are you applying *from*? I didn’t see this particular question last time I used the online system, but I doubt you should answer ‘no’ as this would probably imply you are staying at a commercial address eg a hotel, and it would not trigger the question about your host’s UK immigration status and/or any other questions relevant to them. That could harm your application if you don’t cover all the info required in your remarks. If no-one on TSE can answer definitively, probably your only option is to contact UKVI for advice.

Comment: I'm applying from Germany. This question is only asked when the applicant is a minor. It was not present in my application.

Comment: That makes sense. See Q7 here https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589168/VAF1-guidance.pdf it would appear there should be a ‘friend’ option

Comment: If you are applying for a minor who's a family member (e.g., your child), and the minor will be staying with you at the stated address, then the answer is the minor is staying with **father** (or whatever your relationship is).

Comment: Indeed, @DavidSupportsMonica is correct. See the question I linked to above, it notes “ …when you start with the children, write the names and GWF numbers for the parents in Part 7 of the application and make an additional note in Part 9.”

Answer (score 8):

If you are applying for a minor who's a family member (e.g., your child), and the minor will be staying with you at the address you stated in the child's application, then the answer is the minor is staying with **father**, or whatever your relationship is.

As @Traveller notes in the comments: Part 7 of the [UK Visa Guidance](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589168/VAF1-guidance.pdf) instructs applicants to write the [child's or children's] names and GWF numbers for the parents in Part 7 of the child's application, and make an additional note in Part 9.

Comment: I disagree that the wording of Part 7 is unambiguous enough to be confident here as to the meaning. To me, the document appears to use the phrasing *staying with* throughout to mean the resident of the private address. By the language in this section, the father **accompanies** the travelling minor, but they are not **staying with** them. If unaccompanied, does that mean they put nothing for Question 7.5? I'd argue clearly not. I do accept that your interpretation in plain English is perfectly logical though, which is why I call it ambiguous.

Comment: @TomW I agree with your observation. Because the form reflects a change of focus from host to parent, the wording is not crystal clear, and could be improved.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica for example if the minor is staying with father, you’re implying that the name, passport detail and contact number will be of the father? Whereas the address would be the UK address of another person. Right?

Comment: @AsadMoeen Indeed, that seems to be the case.

Comment: Instead of selecting the option from the drop down. Just type in Family Friend and hit save it should work.