# Indian - Applying for UK Visit visa (6 months) - Self, housewife and son

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

In May 2024, we are planning (family of 3: me, wife and son, 10 years old) are planning to go on a trip to London and Paris.

We will enter London, stay for 2 weeks, from there take the Eurostar train to Paris and then return back to London to board the return flight to India on the same day.

We are planning to apply for a UK visa (with keep my passport option) and then in parallel apply for a France visa as well (biometrics on same day).

A few questions:

1. For my wife's UK visa application form, I am asked this question: "Will someone be paying for your trip". Answers can be Yes or No.    The obvious answer is "Yes" as I will be paying for it.  However if I select Yes, it asks me for documents thinking I am a sponsor living in the UK, as part of the document checklist at the end of the application.
   If I select "No", it just asks for travel document and evidence of funds (however as a housewife she does not have any financial proof).

What should be our answer to this question in the UK Visit visa application "Yes" or "No"? And what financial document should we provide?

2. Will it be ok to show a return from London and not from Paris directly?
3. Will it be ok to apply in parallel or would UKVI need a proof that we have a valid Paris visa as we are going from London to Paris and back?

Comment: You need to cross-ref all the applications as described here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas *France* may want proof of your UK visa

Comment: @Traveller. - Thank you for your time and advice!  Follow up --- France may want proof of UK Visa ---  as i am applying it parallel - can i just attach the application submission receipts ? would that suffice..  UKVI seem to  allow "Keep your passport" feature..

Comment: If you plan to show a return from London rather than from Paris, IMHO France will likely want to see proof that you can enter the UK. An application is not proof. UKVI won’t care if you’re going to Paris or not, UK visitor visas are multiple entry as standard and the UK does not require applicants to provide flight bookings.

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting she is your wife so if you upload your document it will be fine after all you will have to provide evidence that she is your wife  with ID and bank statement etc that means she dependent  financially on you or you are supporting her

So provide your finances.

In this case if you have a joint bank statement or your personal bank and Income Tax proof should be sufficient

You can apply to any number of visas as long as they don’t keep your passport

You need multiple entry visa (which is the standard UK visitor visa is) for you and your family since you are planning to go UK and then France and then Back to UK.

Comment: A UK visitor visa *is* multiple entry