# Can one apply for a UK Visit Visa and France Schengen visa together / in parallel?

Tags: uk, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

I am from India (with no UK or Schengen visa), visiting London and Paris. Entering London first, staying there for 2 weeks. From London, taking the Eurostar to Paris, staying there for a week and then returning back to London via the Eurostar and then from London taking a flight back home (India).

I am planning to apply for a UK Visit Visa and Schengen visa in parallel using the "Keep your passport" facility provided by UKVI.

Will France consider/review/approve my visa application without a UK visit visa (as it will be still in processing) or should I first get the UK visa and then apply for France (Schengen visa)?

Comment: Pretty sure I’ve seen the same question on this site very recently

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indian - Applying for UK Visit visa (6 months) - Self, housewife and son](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/186060/indian-applying-for-uk-visit-visa-6-months-self-housewife-and-son)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While we have seen questions here saying otherwise, it is usually recommended to apply for visas in “reverse order”, I.e. the one for the latest country first.

This is because it’s likely the French consulate will ask for evidence of how you will leave the country, and thus require the UK visa to be sure you can actually leave.

The UK visa application should not need evidence of the French visa as you have a plan to leave the UK back to your home country.

Comment: @RossMillikan UK is both the first and last visit, with France inbetween. The OP is flying back to India from the UK.

Comment: @Ross latest country is Britain...jcaron is right

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help / guidance and time!