# Indian - Applying for wife (dependent on me) - Visit visa for UK

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, applications, evidence

I was applying for a UK standard visit visa and was filling up the application form for my wife. She is a housewife with no source of income.

After filling the application form, at the end the documents / evidence section shows this point:

- Evidence that your sponsor is not, or will not be, in breach of UK immigration laws at the time of your visit

What evidence should I/we be providing here? I am going to be accompanying her for this trip and would be bearing all the expenses. We have no one in the UK and have no UK immigration history or any connection whatsoever.

Comment: "She is a housewife with no source of income." Yes she has. It's called being married.

Comment: AFAIK, since you are not a UK resident and are applying from outside the UK, that particular section doesn’t apply to you. You should complete your own visa application first, then x-ref that to your wife’s application eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas