# For a UK visa, do I need to provide any sponsor letter for my adult daughter and son?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, family

We all are travelling together (myself, wife, son and daughter). Son and daughter are students so not earning money. My wife is also working.

Comment: IMHO, no. Applying as a family you are the primary applicant and you can explain your financial sponsorship in the application. See [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas) for how to complete the applications

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are the primary traveler (who has the sponsorship letter from the host) and your family are just companions. There is no set requirement as a sponsorship letter for your children. However, you must satisfy your visa handling officer that you are able to take care of them financially for the complete travel duration. In most of the cases, I have observed from my friends that visa case officer rejects such applications.

If this is not the case and your intention is purely tourism, and kids want to travel to UK, you apply as a standard tourist visa. And still in that case there is no thing as a sponsorship letter kinda thing. All the required documents are listed in the checklist.