# My spouse and I are planning to visit UK for both our graduations in the same university. Do we need to submit separate visa applications?

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications, sri-lankan-citizens

My spouse and I are planning to visit the UK for both our graduations in the same university. Do we need to submit separate visa applications?

We are both Sri Lankan citizens, residents of Dubai. My spouse is employed here, while I operate my own business in Sri Lanka. Could you please let me know the necessary supporting documents for our travel visa application, considering our respective employment statuses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are both visa nationals, you need to apply separately. However, you should link the two applications together by following the *‘apply as a family’* process explained in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas)

- first complete the application for the primary applicant and indicate in Part 9 that they are the primary. Write down their GWF number. Then proceed to make a fresh application for the other adult and put the primary's GWF number in Part 9 of their application.

For documentation required, see UKVI’s [Guide to supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk)

Comment: Could you please advise what specific financial documentation should be provided if my husband is sponsoring the trip? Specifically, in the savings and investments section of the application, is there a minimum amount required for visa approval? Since he sponsoring the visit,  do I also need to provide financial documents in my application as well?

Comment: @SanduniSilva You do need to provide the same documents, sponsor nonwhistanding. They want to gauge you and not the sponsor

Comment: @NicolasFormichella  is there a minimum amount required to be the bank balance for visa approval?

Comment: @SanduniSilva No, unlike Schengen countries UK guidance does not specify a minimum amount. What *is* important is a) to demonstrate affordability and b) to evidence the source of funds eg via payslips