# How to intentionally get denied visa to the South Africa, without getting into trouble?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, south-africa, deception

I was going to study abroad in South Africa in summer but there was a change of plan and I couldn't go anymore. However, I have to pay 50% of fee if I want to cancel the program. The only way to not pay the penalty is if my visa was denied. I am a Taiwanese citizen living in the U.S, and I was just wondering what can I say to the South Africa consulate located in the U.S to reject my visa?

Comment: I can't tell whether this is a great question or horribly off-topic here. However good luck!

Comment: Hard to answer such a question. Maybe a lack of vaccines or a disease could "help" but not sure if any vaccine is mandatory or any disease is prohibited there.

Comment: I don't know what 50% of the fee is, but if you have a clean history then intentionally attracting a refusal may cost a whole lot more in the long run. Adventurous.  Bordering on deceptive?

Comment: You are asking us to help you with **fraud** against the summer program organizers.

Comment: I'm seldom sympathetic to fraud, but I have no doubt there is a wait-listed applicant who will pay full tuition and the organizers are just getting a bonus,

Comment: What exactly do you count as 'getting in trouble'. Being rejected a visa for South Africa now is likely to have notable impact on your chance to get another visa for South Africa any time in the future. Except from that, there are several questions in the application form, where you can give interesting details about yourself. Claiming to have a mental deficiency and being a Grand Exchequer of the KKK will probably give the SA embassy a fair reason to reject your application.

Comment: Related (certainly not a dupe, but might give inspiration): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24540/how-to-intentionally-get-denied-entry-to-the-us-without-getting-into-trouble

Comment: Have you already applied for your visa, or have you not submitted your application yet?