# Can you ask your government to prevent certain people from getting visas to visit your country?

Tags: visas, europe, visa-refusals

This question is inspired from the situation of the woman who asked ["How to intentionally get denied entry to the US, without getting into trouble?"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24540/how-to-intentionally-get-denied-entry-to-the-us-without-getting-into-trouble/24553#24553). Some of the suggestions people gave her would have put her life and the life of some of her family in danger e.g. like simply saying no and staying in Spain.

My questions is: if certain people posed a threat to your life and/or freedom (and this was provable), could you ask your government to deny those people visas when they apply for them?

For situations like user11743's it would be ideal if, when the visas were denied, the undesired peoples could not trace the reason for denial back to you. 
I'm also asking for both cases: where you have citizenship of the country you're residing in *and* where you don't have citizenship.

Of course, the undesired peoples could find their way to you illegally but this would put one more obstacle in their way.

Many people each year flee their country because of the threat of a certain individual but I have never heard of a government denying that certain person from entering the persons country of refuge, so maybe it's not possible.

Is this kind of request possible in any country in the European Union?

*Disclamer: I understand that once someone enters the country, you can ask the police for protection from that someone but it is up to them to decide if your life is in enough danger to warrant protection. I am just asking to see if there is something you can do to prevent them from entering the country.*

Comment: This question is very broad because it may differ per country.

Comment: I am keeping it general because different people have information about different countries. Information about requesting other people's visas to be denied in _any_ country would quench my curiosity.

Comment: The problem is that visa/immigration laws are different enough to be _different_ worldwide. Yes, Schengen might make most of Europe the same, but there are hundreds of countries worldwide. This is like almost the definition of _too broad_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Canada this is probably possible.  Whether they would actually implement your request is hard to know, but if you had good evidence someone would come here to commit a crime (and harming you would be criminal), it is hard to imagine that that fact wouldn't be considered in requests for a visa or requests to enter Canada.

The most productive direction for such requests would be through your Member of Parliament.  A request could possibly also be made through Canada Border Services Agency.

I've not heard of it being done, but if your evidence is strong, I have confidence Canada would do what it could to prevent someone from entering Canada to conduct acts of ill will.

Answer (score 0):

As a (concerned) citizen, you can bring information to the attention of law enforcement agencies if you think that a crime or other illegal act did happen or is about to happen.

So if you were to overhear in a cafe, "he'll go to *whereever* on a tourist visa, but he'll really work in the kitchen of his cousin's restautant, the passport number is 1234 and the visa number is 4321," and you could make it credible that the information is genuine and accurate, that person might face pointed questions on immigration.

For a random citizen, the problem is twofold:

- Are your priorities on who should be barred and why the same as those of your nation?
- Are you sufficiently credible that they will act on your information?

---

Take the occasional questions on Travel S.E. on how to break or circumvent rules. One could take the question and forward it to immigration authorities. "Here, look at that, ask NSA if they can match that IP to a real person, then you can deny/cancel the visa as appropriate."

Won't happen, of course. First, there are countless other things the immigrations authorities have to do, with much more solid evidence. Next, NSA has lots of data, but they won't release all they know to another agency (possibly even a foreign one) for such a minor matter.